# Spring Application Context Load Order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

On my web.xml I have a "springmvc" servlet declaration (which has a corresponding springmvc-servlet.xml)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also have my usual applicationContext.xml file.

Which one gets loaded first? The springmvc-servlet.xml or the applicationContext.xml?

The reason I'm asking this is whenever I place the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` element in the applicationContext.xml, I get a Severe Context error. But when I put that element in the springmvc-servlet.xml, my web app runs fine.

Any ideas why?

On another web-app, I have the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` inside the applicationContext.xml and it runs fine.

Addendum: 
I do notice that the presence of **aop:config** poses conflict against **mvc:annotation-driven**

Comment: Please, copy exception stack trace to your question. Do you have defined xsd for mvc namespace in the applicationContext.xml?

Comment: There's no stack trace. I only get the typical Severe Context error from Tomcat.

Answer (score 5):

the `applicationContext.xml` context is parent to the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` context. I don't know whether this means it is loaded first, but it does not matter in your case:

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` must be in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, because it belongs to the web-part of the application.

Comment: Based on observation, I don't think so. I have a web-app where the <mvc:annotation-driven /> is in the applicationContext.xml. In fact, if I put in the xxxxx-servlet, I just get SEVERE CONTEXT error. I need that element because my Controllers and Servicers are marked using the annotations @Controller and @Service respectively

Comment: @chris how about sharing the exact message and trace of the serve exception?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem!

It turns out it has nothing to do with the load order or where the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is declared.

I tried deploying my web-app on another Tomcat and to my surprise there's a stack trace in the localhost log. I had a hint by trial and error that the conflict is with `<aop:config/>`. But what particular conflict?

Then I saw this error in the log file:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$Array cannot be cast to org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType
```

So we have a cast exception. I googled that exact error above and found this: [Spring 3: adding  causes ClassCastException](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=82187)

It appears the thread starter and I have the same exact issue. So I downloaded the aspectj-1.6.10.jar but I was still missing a class. Then it turns out it should be the **aspectjweaver-1.6.9**

I was still using a very old aspectjweaver. It didn't have any version on its name. Problem solved. Case closed.

By the way as a bonus, I've manually unrolled the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` element to its equivalent xml declaration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
<bean id="conversion-service" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

They're exactly the same when you declare the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` based on what I've researched.

Thanks to everybody who helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Except for web.xml there is no predefined order.
This happens:

- web.xml is loaded by the servlet engine, this triggers the load of all defined servlets, filters, listeners,
- the ContextLoaderListener loads the
  root application context XML, this
  might include a bean definition for a
  LocalSessionFactoryBean, triggering
  the load of all Hibernate mapping XML
  files
- the DispatcherServlet loads the web
  application context XML

Study the web.xml to determine the order in each case.

see also:

[link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=30124)

Comment: In my web.xml I only have the xxxxx-servlet.xml. I didn't declare any other Spring XML files. The applicationContext.xml is loaded by default without any special config. I don't really know why it works on some apps based on their location

Comment: I'm digesting this info and currently testing...I think I'm into something

Comment: Ok great, I'm glad that this info is helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add the mvc namespace to the application context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"
>
```

(other namespaces stripped)

Comment: I got those already. Eclipse will automatically complain when I'm missing those schemas

Comment: Thought so, but I was just checking, for completeness.